# How to collect convenience fee with Cartthrob, based on total fees

Tags: cartthrob

I am utilizing CartThrob to collect invoice payments, since several of my clients have been requesting it. The invoices can be up to $20,000. If my clients want to pay by CC, then I want them to pay the CC charges, loosing $300 on a $10,000 invoice hurts just a little bit. So I am trying to get CartThrob to calculate the convenience fee. I have tried several things…

---

Using CartThrobs shipping function

This works quite well. I can set the shipping fee to be a percentage of the total fees and CartThrob automatically adds it to the total to be processed. But then in the future, if I ever need to charge shipping fees, I can't.

---

Using **add_to_cart** function

I began to test this. First I added a product and used the **add_to_cart** function to add it to the cart. But parameters from the **add_to_cart_form** such as **allow_user_price** and **price** do not work,  they don't override the price set in the product entry.

This was quite promising because I would use the **delete_from_cart** function just before the **add_to_cart** function so I could always reset the price., not in

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why add_to_cart_form with **allow_user_price** and **price** would not work. Could you post the code you have? I use this in many of the products I've created to allow for dynamically created prices. You could try placing a price input field within the form rather than it being a parameter. I have an example of this below where I use it for adding additional charges on a separate page when customers are requested to pay a little more:

```
{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form 
    {!-- return="{template_group}/basket" --}

    on_the_fly="y"
    title="Nominal charge"

    tax_exempt="no"
    shipping_exempt="yes"

    allow_user_price="yes"
    allow_user_shipping="no"

    id="charges_form"

}
    <fieldset>
        <p><label>Type:</label>
            <select name="item_options[type]">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <option value="Additional delivery charge">Additional delivery charge</option>
                <option value="Additional product cost">Additional product cost</option>
                <option value="Other separate payment">Separate payment</option>
                <option value="Returns">Returns</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p><label>Description:</label> <input name="item_options[description]" value="" class="input" /></p>
        <p><label>Order ref:</label> <input name="item_options[order_ref]" value="" class="input" placeholder="Order number if applicable" /></p>
        <p><label>Amount:</label> <span class="price_field"><span class="prefix">{exp:cartthrob:view_setting prefix="yes"}</span><input name="price" value="" class="input small" /></span> <small>(excl VAT)</small></p>
    </fieldset> 
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button purple r" />
{/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}
```

Of course you could place this anywhere, say at the bottom of the cart area before.

I hope this helps